# Yum php 7.2 install dependency errors (Centos 6)

Tags: php, centos, dependencies, php-7, yum

I'm running Centos 6 and am trying to update our PHP version from 5.4 to 7.2.

So far I've installed the Remi and EPEL repository as instructed by several guides.

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-6.rpm epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
```

Then I've ran

```
yum install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
yum update -y
```

I've also tried different variants of this such as `yum --enablerepo=remi-php72 install php-xml php-soap php-xmlrpc php-mbstring php-json php-gd php-mcrypt`

When I try to run this however I get the following error

> Error: Package: gd-last-2.2.5-5.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-safe)
>              Requires: libfontconfig.so.1()(64bit)  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

I tried looking up if I could install `libfontconfig.so.1` and found this:

```
yum install fontconfig freetype freetype-devel fontconfig-devel libstdc++
```

This however did not work either as it only returned

```
No package fontconfig available. 
No package freetype-devel available.
No package fontconfig-devel available.
```

In addition, I've also tried running `yum update -y --skip-broken` as suggested by the error code. When running this I get no error. However, it still doesn't seem like the new PHP version is being installed and I get a notice saying that the following packages where skipped

```
gd-last-2.2.5-5.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-safe
libargon2-20161029-7.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-safe
libwebp-0.4.3-3.el6.x86_64 from epel
php-7.2.17-1.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
php-cli-7.2.17-1.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
php-common-7.2.16-1.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
php-common-7.2.17-1.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
php-gd-7.2.17-1.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
php-json-7.2.17-1.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
php-ldap-7.2.17-1.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
php-mbstring-7.2.17-1.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
php-mysqlnd-7.2.17-1.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
php-pdo-7.2.17-1.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
php-pecl-apcu-5.1.16-1.el6.remi.7.2.x86_64 from remi-php72
php-pecl-apcu-5.1.17-1.el6.remi.7.2.x86_64 from remi-php72
php-pecl-apcu-bc-1.0.5-1.el6.remi.7.2.x86_64 from remi-php72
php-pecl-mcrypt-1.0.2-2.el6.remi.7.2.x86_64 from remi-php72
php-soap-7.2.17-1.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
php-xml-7.2.17-1.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
php-xmlrpc-7.2.17-1.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
```

I feel like I'm a bit out of my depth and would appreciate any help on this.

**Edit**

I decided to start from scratch by restoring my server to a previous backup and followed the guide here: https://tecadmin.net/nstall-php7-on-centos6/ which seems to have solved my issue.

Comment: Looks like "base" repository was missing

Comment: Is your os running in virtual machine?